# How to call a model in controller ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Portfolio::PortfolioImage < PortfolioPost

  has_attached_file :file,
                    styles: { _medium: ["960x", :jpg] },
                    default_style: :original,
                    preserve_files: true,
                    path: base_upload_url+ ":assign_user_id" + "_" + ":file_name" + ".jpg"

  validates_attachment_content_type :file, content_type: /\Aimage/

  before_post_process :downcase_file_name

  def downcase_file_name
    self.file_file_name = self.file_file_name.downcase
  end
end

  def index
    @portfolio_image = PortfolioImage.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    @portfolio_video = PortfolioVideo.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    @portfolio_doc = PortfolioDocument.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    render json: @portfolio_image
    render json: @portfolio_video
    render json: @portfolio_doc
  end
```

How to solve this problem I have to create an api for index action where three types of data I have to see when chosen image only images should show and if chosen video only video should show.?

Comment: Looks like you can call the model just fine.

Comment: no it will not work directly because that model PortfolioImage is related to PortfolioPost thats why any other clue or idea.

Comment: @Mr.Ardor What do you mean by "it will not work"? Could you add the error with its backtrace to the question, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think what you're missing is the Module prefix.
For ex. to get all portfolio images you want to use `Portfolio::PortfolioImage.all`. (Except when you're calling from inside the module, but that's not very clear from your question)